# Is this a valid application of Autoencodeers/VAE?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, autoencoders, prediction, variational-autoencoder

I am trying to predict a spectrum (1D vector) from various scalar inputs which are known to be correlated. As the spectrum vector is very long (4000 points) it was suggested that I use dimensionality reduction, rather than trying to produce a NN which has a 4000 output size. So, train an autoencoder on the spectra, encode the spectra, then use a neural network to predict the encoded spectra from the various inputs, and then reconstruct the spectra by decoding the predicted encoded spectra.

It was further suggested to me that

A VAE would be a better solution here than an autoencoder, as the structure of the encoded spectra may make it easier for the neural network to learn.

I should use a KL-Divergence term on the output of the neural network predicting the encoded spectra. Not sure on the justification of this one.

Are either of these points valid? Or, indeed, is the use of an autoencoder the way to go here at all? I should ay we are also data limited (around 700 points total).

I have already given it a bit of a go with a little bit of success, but I wanted to check if this is a good way forward before investing too much time/resource

Comment: You've probably answered this question yourself by now, but I'm responding in case others will find it useful... These are all sensible ideas, indeed they were used by Wu and Peek for predicting galaxy spectra in this preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.12318. The use of a KL divergence term is a fundamental part of VAEs -- it arises from the theory behind VAEs, though some flavours of VAE do modify the KL divergence term (which undermines its theoretical basis but can improve performance). The dataset is quite small for the proposed approach but it might be competitive with other options.